# Why does a charge placed on the same plane as the face of the hemishphere NOT affect the electric flux from the point charge at the centre?

Tags: electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Why doesn't an external charge placed at A or C as in this image not contribute to any change to the already existing electric flux of the hemisphere due to *q*?
[image]

Comment: It doesn't change the flux **due to q** because it's a different charge. It will add an additional flux due to A or C.

Comment: From Gauss's law, the integral of the flux over a surface enclosing q won't change due to a charge at location A or C. But the flux at each specific point on the surface will change. They will just change in such a way as to not change the integral over the whole surface.

Comment: @ThePhoton:  The surface in question is open.  It doesn't enclose any charge at all.  And charges at $A$ or $C$ will contribute zero net flux to the surface, though this is not the case for charges at $B$ or $D$.  Longer answer to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that we can figure out the flux through a surface due to a bunch of charges by looking at the flux due to each individual charge in isolation.  This is because the electric field obeys superposition (the field of A and B together is the field of A plus the field of B), and because flux is linear in the electric field.  That means that we can ignore $q$ entirely and focus on what the flux through the surface from a charge at $A$, $B$, $C$, or $D$ if $q$ wasn't there.

Second, think of the flux as proportional to the "number of net field lines" that pass through the surface.  If we put a charge at point $A$ or at point $C$ (again, assuming that $q$ was absent), then every field line radiating from the charge would either miss the surface entirely or would pass through it twice.  And it's not too hard to see that all the  field lines that pass through the surface twice do so once "from above" and once "from below", making opposite contributions to the flux.  Thus, there are no "net field lines" passing through the surface, and the net flux is zero.

Note that this argument does not hold for a hypothetical charge at points $B$ or $D$.

Comment: Would you clarify how field line passing once through above get cancelled out by the one passing from down below? Flux = E.ds seems to be different to me in both the cases.